# How to create CodeBlocks IDE C++ project to work on existing shared library project?

Tags: c++, linux, ide, shared-libraries, codeblocks

I am working on a C++ project that utilizes the Open Motion Planning Library (OMPL) on a Linux system. The project requires that I consistently add features to the OMPL source code. The project also includes independent files that utilize the OMPL shared library, but should not be included in the installed shared library.

What is the best way to set up this project in the CodeBlocks IDE so that I can fluidly edit and test both the library code and independent code?

Previously, I was using Atom and the terminal to code and run the program. I used Make and Cmake to rebuild and reinstall the library as I made updates. Now, I want to utilize the debugger features of the CodeBlocks IDE, and am trying to find the best way to set up the project to optimize workflow in an IDE. I do not regularly use IDEs, and appreciate any guidance on best practices and workflow strategies for a project like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the codeblocks IDE you can create, open and work on different projects (dependent or independent they are). 
You can save a workspace file that includes related projects. A workspace is a collection of projects.
You can select the project you are interested in and work on that (compiling and debugging), for example the OMPL library, whether it is used as a static or dynamic library.
 
You can then activate the calling application project, add independent files to it, compile it, testing and debug it.
 
Application projects that use the OMPL library can also be many, and include several independent files.